# Unnecessary space in output when using Write-Host

Tags: powershell

When I use `Write-Host` within a `Foreach-Object`, I get an unnecessary space in the output.

```
write-host "http://contoso.com/personal/"$_.ADUserName
```

Output:

```
http://contoso.com/personal/ john.doe
```

How can I remove the space before john? Trim does not work because there is no space in `$_.ADUserName`

Comment: `write-host "http://contoso.com/personal/$($_.ADUserName)"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is happening because Write-Host is considering your constant string and your object to be two separate parameters -- you aren't actually joining the strings together the way you're calling it.  Instead of calling it this way, actually concatenate the strings:

```
write-host "http://contoso.com/personal/$($_.ADUserName)"
```

or

```
write-host ("http://contoso.com/personal/" + $_.ADUserName)
```

or

```
write-host ("http://contoso.com/personal/{0}" -f $_.ADUserName)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it without `write-host`:

```
"http://contoso.com/personal/{0}" -f $_.ADUserName
```

Comment: Though one shouldn't get in the habit of using Write-Host, I'll agree, this statement is not equivalent.  Instead, this statement is equivalent to using Write-Output, not Write-Host.